# Remove auto-link formatting from Google Sheet via api

Tags: google-sheets-api

When using Google Sheets Api to create automated reports I've found that any string that ends with ".com" automatically gets formatted as a link (I've attached a picture). I'd like to remove this formatting via the api, Is this possible?

[Two examples of the autolink formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y75WH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the hyperlink format to the plain text format using "hyperlinkDisplayType". The endpoint and request body are as follows. As a sample, the request body removes the hyperlink format of cells "A1:A3".  I thought that from the image of your question, `repeatCell` might be suitable for your situation.

#### Endpoint :

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheet ID ###:batchUpdate
```

#### Request body :

```
{
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "repeatCell": 
      {
        "cell": 
        {
          "userEnteredFormat": 
          {
            "hyperlinkDisplayType": "PLAIN_TEXT"
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.hyperlinkDisplayType",
        "range": 
        {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 3,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Note :

- This answer supposes that you can use Sheets API.

#### Reference :

- [HyperlinkDisplayType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#HyperlinkDisplayType)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.